# Logging with Discord.js (using FS)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I'm developing a bot, which has a suggestion feature.
You can type `!suggest <suggestion>` and then the bot outputs an embed with the suggestion in a channel - that works and I like it, but I also want it to log it into either a `.txt` file or a `.json` file, but I cant figure out how to do that.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should refer to official guides and post here only the issues related to them. here's a good start https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin

Answer (score 2):

like Thecave3 said you should prob read docs and learn nodejs before you use a library like discord.js

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

but anyways this would be the code

```js
fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(object), (err) => {
   if(err) console.error(err);
});
```